# What is the difference between apk built in ci/cd on gitlab and one built in Android studio

Tags: android, gitlab-ci

I have an Android project and it's on gitlab with ci/cd configured according to this article
https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/

I build **debug version** of the app both on gitlab and in Android Studio
The apk files are different, although their content are identical. The gitlab apk doesn't install on the phone(the play market protection error). The Android studio file does install on the phone.

Is there any meta data in jar (zip?) files? From what I see (by looking at the Meta-Inf folder) both are not signed. What could be the difference between them?

Please advise

Comment: tip: there is an [APK analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer) built-in into Android Studio, in which you can check te difference between these two APKs. BTW. "both are not signed" - thats impossible to install APK not signed with any key

Comment: @snachmsm I compared two folders extracted from jar, apkanalyzer shows exactly the same - 0 bytes difference. "both are not signed" - with release key of course.
Anyway, thank you for you tip!